# Error reducing astronomy picture flatfield PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to reduce my cannon astro images by taking off the flatframe, which works. But it leaves all the values very low (so almost black picture), which is why I also want to multiply it with the average. However this gives me an error. (while without multiplication it works.)

Does anybody know why?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\astro\10-12\moon\fits\red.py", line 16, in 
>       img = Image.fromarray(imarray)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1886, in fromarray
>       raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type") TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

Here is my code

```
import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('8bit/DPP_0001.TIF')
flat = Image.open('8bit/flat2.TIF')
#im.show()


imarray = np.array(im)
flatarray = np.array(flat)

avg = np.average(imarray)
imarray = (imarray/flatarray)*avg

img = Image.fromarray(imarray)

img.save("done/aap.png","png")
```

Comment: Check `imarray.shape` before and after the multiply, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700193/pil-cannot-handle-this-data-type

Comment: `>>> imarray = np.array(im)
>>> imarray.shape
(2848, 4272, 3)
>>> avg = np.average(imarray)

>>> imarray = (imarray/flatarray)*avg
>>> imarray.shape
(2848, 4272, 3)`

The shape did not change with me oddly

Comment: Maybe a data type/range issue?  Check `imarray.dtype` before/after and try `imarray = numpy.uint8(imarray)` before `fromarray`.

Comment: Ah it was a float instead of a unit8! `imarray = np.uint8((imarray/flatarray)*avg)` Worked :D

Post it and I'll upvote you :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL's `Image.fromarray()` supports a limited range of input type/channel combinations (see `PIL/Image.py`, member `_fromarray_typemap`).

The original `imarray` loaded from the TIF file had 3 channels of 8-bit integer values (bytes).

In your case, the average value of the image yielded a float value, and when that was multiplied with the image data, it produced float values for all of the pixels.

For `fromarray` to work, you need to coerce the pixel values back to byte values with `np.uint8( ... )`.