# PIL TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an image stored in a numpy array that I want to convert to `PIL.Image` in order to perform an interpolation only available with PIL.

When trying to convert it through `Image.fromarray()` it raises the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

I have read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700193/pil-cannot-handle-this-data-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51979554/typeerror-cannot-handle-the-data-type-in-pil-image) but they do not seem to help in my situation.

What I'm trying to run:

```
from PIL import Image

x  # a numpy array representing an image, shape: (256, 256, 3)

Image.fromarray(x)
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Please show an example of how your data looks, else it's impossible to say what the issue is.

Comment: @desertnaut I thought that since I use the images for classification with a CNN the tags might be relevant.

Comment: No, tags should be only about the question *content*, not the *context*; no problem, just keep it in mind for the future

Answer (score 171, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Does `x` contain `uint` values in [0, 255]? If not and especially if `x` ranges from 0 to 1, that is the reason for the error.

---

#### Explanation

Most image libraries (e.g. matplotlib, opencv, scikit-image) have two ways of representing images:

- as `uint` with values ranging from 0 to 255.
- as `float` with values ranging from 0 to 1.

The latter is more convenient when performing operations between images and thus is more popular in the field of Computer Vision.
However PIL seems to **not support it for RGB images**.

If you take a look [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/63141a9c0cf1d08d58c63249dc785bba4295e86c/src/PIL/Image.py#L2573)
it seems that when you try to read an image from an array, if the array has a shape of `(height, width, 3)` it automatically assumes it's an RGB image and **expects it to have a `dtype` of `uint8`**!
In your case, however, you have an RBG image with `float` values from 0 to 1.

---

#### Solution

You can fix it by converting your image to the format expected by PIL:

```
im = Image.fromarray((x * 255).astype(np.uint8))
```

Comment: This actually helped! It's disappointing that PIL doesn't support RBG images with values in [0, 1].

Comment: I am getting the following warning  messeage `Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8. Range [0, 1]. Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning.` What does Range [0,1] mean? My range of x was [0,2]

Comment: @BlackJack21 I think it means that you should first convert your range to [0,1] then try converting it yo uint8

Comment: No, I tried to do that as well but the error remained. This was on Jupyter Lab, could it be something related to ipynb?

Comment: @BlackJack21 no it doesn't have anything to do with the environment. The problem is the package (i.e. PIL) itself...

Comment: Converting the type to `np.uint8` did it! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you!  Life saver!  I used this without *255:

im = Image.fromarray((x).astype(np.uint8))

Comment: This gives: `AttributeError: dtype`

Answer (score 27):

I **solved** it different way.

*Problem Situation:*
When working with ***gray image*** or ***binary image***, if the numpy array shape is `(height, width, 1)`, this error will be raised also.
For example, a 32 by 32 pixel gray image (value 0 to 255)

```py
np_img = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(32, 32, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
# np_img.shape == (32, 32, 1)
pil_img = Image.fromarray(np_img)
```

will raise `TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 1), |u1`

### Solution:

If the image shape is like `(32, 32, 1)`, **reduce dimension** into `(32, 32)`

```py
np_img = np.squeeze(np_img, axis=2)  # axis=2 is channel dimension 
pil_img = Image.fromarray(np_img)
```

This time it works!!

Additionally, please make sure the `dtype` is `uint8`(for gray) or `bool`(for binary).

Answer (score 9):

In my case it was only because I forgotted to add the "RGB" arg in the "fromarray" func.

```
pil_img = Image.fromarray(np_img, 'RGB')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a different issue for the same error in my case. The image I used was in RGBA format, so before using fromarray() function just convert it to RGB using the convert() function and it will work perfectly fine.

```
image_file = Image.open(image_file)
image_file = image_file.convert('RGB')
```

P.S.: Posting this solution as an initial step, before converting the image to np.

Answer (score 0):

In my case file format of the images was changed to `png` to `jpg`. It worked well when I corrected the image format of the error images.

Answer (score 0):

According to the **scikit-image**'s [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.html), you can convert an image to unsigned byte format, with values in **[0, 255]** using `img_as_ubyte`:

```
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
from PIL import Image

new_image = Image.fromarray(img_as_ubyte(image))
```