# Resizing numpy image arrays

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I am running a neural network, whose input should be of size `(128, 128, 3)`. I have a dataset of images of size `(256, 256, 3)`

So, I am resizing every image `img` before inputting to neural network.

```
img.resize(128, 128, 3)
```

It is working well for some batches or some epochs.

But suddenly the program returns error due to resizing image as follows

```
ValueError: resize only works on single-segment arrays
```

I thought that there may be some issue with shape of images in my dataset, but the shapes of image are same through out my dataset i.e., `(256, 256, 3)`. And I have no clue about this error.

If there is any issue with the `resize` function, then how does it work for some images and pops-up error for some other? Am I wrong anywhere?

Comment: check `img.size` for image before `img.resize` then grab error

Comment: @SurajS I checked it, it is printing the same  shape `(256, 256, 3)` for the image causing error also.

Comment: is the resize method used here the `np.resize`? if yes, the doc says it is not suitable for images

Comment: I think at some point in your computation some of your arrays get segmented (i.e. the array is not a contiguous area of memory anymore), **maybe** due to low available memory. But anyway `np.resize` doesn't do what you think it does here: it just chops off the array to the new size. If you want to resize the image by half it's easy: just take every second pixel `img = img[::2,::2,:]`

Answer (score 1):

For images, resizing using PIL is one possible method.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
np.array(Image.fromarray(img.astype(np.uint8)).resize((256, 256))).astype('float32')
```

as explained at [TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 3), <f4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60138697/typeerror-cannot-handle-this-data-type-1-1-3-f4)