# storing image (.tif) in np.array through PIL fromarray [TypeError: Cannot handle this data type][ValueError: invalid literal for int()]

Tags: numpy, python-imaging-library, tiff, python-tesseract

**update**
when i write (as answerer said)

```
with open('results.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in results:
        f.write(line)
        f.write('\n')
```

all text pieces are appended correctly into `result.txt`. But when i go into the cmd and do
`magick -density 288 text:"result.txt" -alpha off -compress Group4 filename1.tif`
it creates `filename1.tif` with all of the `result.txt` characters as a picture.

---

Original question:
This code accesses a folder of single page .tif files and extracts textual data.

```
data = []
data1 = []
listOfPages = glob.glob(r"C:/Users/name/folder/*.tif")
for entry in listOfPages:
    if os.path.isfile(entry):
        filenames = entry
    data1.append(filenames)
    text1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(
            Image.open(entry), lang="en"
        )
    text = re.sub(r'\n',' ', text1)     
    regex1 = re.compile(r'(www(i|ı)a\s+bbb(\:)?(\s+|\s+\.)?\s+(de(s|r(:)?))?)', flags = re.IGNORECASE)
        
    try:
        var1a = regex1.search(text)
        if var1a:
            var1 = var1a.group(1)
        else:
            var1 = None
    except:
        pass
        
    data.append([text, var1])
    
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['raw_text', 'var1'])
df01= pd.DataFrame(data1,columns =['filename'])
df1 = pd.concat([df0, df01], axis=1)
```

I wanted to adjust it in order to work for multipage files, too. Therefore i am trying to convert it through Image.fromarray() which raises the following error:

`text1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(np.array(entry), lang="en")`
or
`text1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(np.array(entry)), lang="en")`

`TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1), <U52`

I use `python 3.9.7 pytesseract 0.3.8 numpy 1.21.2 pillow 8.3.2`
I read this [PIL TypeError: Cannot handle this data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319949/pil-typeerror-cannot-handle-this-data-type)
and came up with this

`text1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(np.array(entry * 255).astype(np.uint8)), lang="en")`

which gives me error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'C:/Users/name/folder/test\\fff.tifC:/Users/name/folder/test\\ddddd.tif`

which hints at the need to use float

but when i do

`text1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(np.array(entry * 255).astype(np.float)), lang="en")`

i get

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'C:/Users/name/folder/test\\ffff.tif`

**exiftool output**

```
File Type                       : TIFF
File Type Extension             : tif
MIME Type                       : image/tiff
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Subfile Type                    : Full-resolution image
Image Width                     : 2472
Image Height                    : 3495
Bits Per Sample                 : 1
Compression                     : T6/Group 4 Fax
Photometric Interpretation      : BlackIsZero
Thresholding                    : No dithering or halftoning
Fill Order                      : Reversed
Image Description               : DN31
Camera Model Name               : SCA
Strip Offsets                   : (Binary data 90 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
Samples Per Pixel               : 1
Rows Per Strip                  : 213
Strip Byte Counts               : (Binary data 73 bytes, use -b option to extract)
X Resolution                    : 300
Y Resolution                    : 300
Planar Configuration            : Chunky
T6 Options                      : (none)
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Software                        : DACS Toolkit II
Modify Date                     : 1998:03:12 10:29:31
Image Size                      : 2472x3495
Megapixels                      : 8.6
```

other suggestions on SO are

`im = Image.fromarray((img[0] * 255).astype(np.uint8))` If your image is greyscale, you need to pass PIL a 2-D array, i.e. the shape must be h,w not h,w,1.

```
i = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGB')
a = np.asarray(i, np.uint8)
print(a.shape)

b = abs(np.fft.rfft2(a,axes=(0,1)))
b = np.uint8(b)
j = Image.fromarray(b)
```

By default, it uses the last two axes: axes=(-2,-1). The third axis represents the RGB channels. Instead, it seems more plausible that one would want to perform an FFT over the spatial axes, axes=(0,1)

`img = Image.fromarray(data[0][i].transpose(0,2).numpy().astype(np.uint8))` channel dimension will be the last (rather than the first)

Comment: Surely `entry` is a filename not a Numpy array?

Comment: for each loop, `entry` is a different filename, yes. otherwise i would get different error descriptions

Comment: You can't make a filename into a Numpy array with `np.array(entry*255)`

Comment: Can I suggest you run `exiftool` on your TIFFs to check if they are single channel (greyscale) or colour, whether they are integer or float and so on? Then kindly paste the output for one TIFF into your question (not in comments). Thank you.

Comment: from what i understand from other posts, the problem occurs when the array is created from a filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something more like this to process multipage TIFFs. I have tried to improve your variable names from nondescript names like `data`, `var` to make it more readable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
from glob import glob
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

def processPage(filename, pageNum, im):
    global results
    print(f'Processing: {filename}, page: {pageNum}')

    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang="eng")
    srchResult = regex.search(text)
    if srchResult is not None:
        results.append(srchResult.group(0))

# Compile regex just once, outside loop - it doesn't change
regex = re.compile(r'(\w+\s(Queen|President|Washington|London|security|architect)\s\w+)', flags = re.IGNORECASE)

results = []

# Get list of all filenames to be processed
filenames = glob('folder/*.tif')

# Iterate over all files
for filename in filenames:
    print(f'Processing file: {filename}')
    with Image.open(filename) as im:
        for pageNum, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(im)):
                processPage(filename, pageNum, page)

print('\n'.join(results))
```

---

You don't need to do the rest of this stuff... it's just there so you can see how I generated TIFFs to test with...

I tested it by making 2 multi-page TIFFs from the Wikipedia entries for *"Buckingham Palace"* and *"The White House"* with **ImageMagick** by going to each of those pages, copying and saving the text as `a.txt` and then doing:

```
magick -density 288 text:"a.txt" -alpha off -compress Group4 WhiteHouse.tif
```

**Sample Output**

```
Processing file: folder/Buckingham.tif
Processing: folder/Buckingham.tif, page: 0
Processing: folder/Buckingham.tif, page: 1
Processing: folder/Buckingham.tif, page: 2
Processing file: folder/WhiteHouse.tif
Processing: folder/WhiteHouse.tif, page: 0
Processing: folder/WhiteHouse.tif, page: 1
Processing: folder/WhiteHouse.tif, page: 2
Processing: folder/WhiteHouse.tif, page: 3
Processing: folder/WhiteHouse.tif, page: 4
Processing: folder/WhiteHouse.tif, page: 5
the London residence
stricken Queen withdrew
the president of
George Washington occupied
President Washington
by architect Frederick
in Washington when
House security breaches
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for. There are thousands of those files, so how would i automate the file creation and batch processing rather than needing to write all the filenames manually?

Comment: Ideally you would mention it in your question! Surely the `glob('folder/*.tif')` picks up all the files or is there something else I need to know?

Comment: No, sorry, i think you just overestimate my abilities. I updated my question text

Comment: I don't understand why you are swapping array indices and including lumps of code to do FFTs in your question suddenly. If you go to `C:/Users/name` and run my code, does it correctly find all the correct images when it does the `glob()`? If not, please include something that shows where all the images really are if they are not in `C:/Users/name/folder`.

Comment: it finds them correctly and also appends each regex, that it finds to the `result.txt` file.

Comment: There was no need for you to *"But when i go into the cmd prompt and run `magick density ...`"*. I only showed all that stuff after the dividing line in my answer so that you and others could see how I generated my input files for testing.

Comment: The idea is that you just take `results` list and `filenames` list and put them into your Pandas dataframe.

Comment: Ooh ok well that solves it then, thanks :)