# PIL Not Forming An Image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am new to PIL, so i was playing around with the functions:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
image_array = np.array([   
    [[0, 0, 0],
    [255, 255, 255],
    [0, 0, 0]],
    [[255, 255, 255],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [255, 255, 255]],
    [[0, 0, 0],
    [255, 255, 255],
    [0, 0, 0]]])
image = Image.fromarray(image_array)
image.show()
```

However, when i want to use it, it gives me the following error in the 13th line:
**TypeError**
**Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 3), <i8**
But surprisingly, it doesn't give me an error when i use `image_array = np.array(Image.open('Image.png'))` which is the exact same image with the exact same array:
[Image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU9ZY.png)
(The image is very small, 3 by 3 pixels)

Nobody else seems to have the same problem, or maybe i'm just missing something

Comment: I get this error:  Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 3), <i4

Comment: Possible similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319949/pil-typeerror-cannot-handle-this-data-type?rq=1

Comment: change dtype to `uint8`, as mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with a [datatype conversion](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) or define the array with `dtype=np.unit8` parameter to begin with.

A relevant answer (different question) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319949/pil-typeerror-cannot-handle-this-data-type) as well. -

```
img = Image.fromarray(image_array.astype(np.uint8)) #<---
img.width, img.height
```

```
(3,3)
```

Or, simply use `np.array([[],[],[]], dtype=np.uint8)` to begin with, if memory is an issue.

Further more, if you want to build an array as int64, just use `copy=False` to return the original array instead of a copy, before you hand it over to PIL.

```
image_array.astype(np.unit8, copy=False)
```

Comment: Why not just create the array with that `dtype` from the start, rather than create it incorrectly then change it?

Comment: That's not the point of my answer. Its to point out that a datatype conversion is needed. It's up to OP to decide whether they want to do that dtype specified during the definition of the array. Moreover, they may want to work with the defined array before pushing it to PIL.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your image array with:

```
image_array = np.array([   
[[0, 0, 0],
[255, 255, 255],
[0, 0, 0]],
[[255, 255, 255],
[0, 0, 0],
[255, 255, 255]],
[[0, 0, 0],
[255, 255, 255],
[0, 0, 0]]])
```

It will be `int64`, rather than `np.uint8`. You can check that with:

```
print(image_array.dtype)
```

so it will take 8 times more RAM than necessary. Rather than create something unnecessarily large and then correct it by creating yet another version now requiring 9 times the RAM, I suggest you create it with the correct type in the first place. So, use:

```
image_array = np.array([   
[[0, 0, 0],
[255, 255, 255],
[0, 0, 0]],
[[255, 255, 255],
[0, 0, 0],
[255, 255, 255]],
[[0, 0, 0],
[255, 255, 255],
[0, 0, 0]]], dtype=np.uint8)
```